# What is the best way to manage interdependent indexes

Tags: mysql, index, array

So I have a table of items as so

```
|firstIndex|subIndex|relatedIndexes|
-----------------------------------
|     1    |   1    |  2 ,6 , 8    |
-----------------------------------
|     1    |   2    |  2 ,6 , 8    |
-----------------------------------
|     1    |   3    |  2 ,6 , 8    |
-----------------------------------
|     2    |   1    |  1, 10 , 12  |
-----------------------------------
|     3    |   1    |  20, 50, 77  |
-----------------------------------
|     4    |   1    |  ...         |
-----------------------------------
```

So both `firstIndex` an `subIndex` are the primary keys (they cannot be two times the same combination, hope I'm clear :) ), `subIndex` is the index representing the number of the variation of `firstIndex` and finally `relatedIndexes` is the array of  `firstIndex` related to other `firstIndex`. As you can see in the sample `firstIndex` `1` is related to `firstIndex` `2` and `2` to `1`

My question is how can I represent, store and manage this model the easiest and quickiest way in MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can looks like

```
CREATE TABLE indices (firstIndex INT NOT NULL,
                      subIndex INT NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (firstIndex, subIndex)
                     );

CREATE TABLE refs (baseIndex INT NOT NULL,
                   relatedIndex INT NOT NULL,
                   PRIMARY KEY (baseIndex, relatedIndex),
                   FOREIGN KEY fk_bi (baseIndex) REFERENCES indices (firstIndex),
                   FOREIGN KEY fk_ri (relatedIndex) REFERENCES indices (firstIndex)
                  );
```

---

**Update**

> why there's a baseIndex + relatedIndex

It is a "link" table (instead of non-relational CSV-field `relatedIndexes`). The (2,6,8) value for `firstIndex=1` in a source scheme is transferred to 3 separate records in `refs` with (1,2),(1,6),(1,8) value pairs.

> what is Foreign Key

It is constraint references which do not allow to insert into `refs` an index value which not exists in `indices` table. And prevents deletion a record from `indices` while at least one reference exists in `refs`.

Comment: thanks can you explain a bit more about why there's  a baseIndex + relatedIndex also what is Foreign Key fk_bi and fk_ri. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add these explanations to your answer please.thanks in advance

Comment: Explainations moved to the answer.